# How to avoid SharePoint GUIDs in its database before install

Tags: installation, server-farm, setup

I have a new SharePoint installation to do and i really don't want to have GUIDs in the databases.
What do i need to do before install to avoid this. maybe create the databases before installation or maybe using Powershell.
But what are the steps to take to do this i.e when to use Powershell to install the config DB etc..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best description I've seen is Todd Klindts [How to create a SharePoint 2010 farm with no GUIDs using PowerShell](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=241)

If you've already created your farm you can follow his other post [Getting the GUID out of the AdminContent database in SharePoint 2010](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/lists/posts/post.aspx?id=233)

Comment: Thanks Per.But i don't want to get rid of it i want to avoid it before installation.
Cheers

Comment: Sorry was the wrong post, answer updated

Comment: Thanks.No idea how i missed that on todds blog.Do you know if i can use this approach for services applications too?

Comment: Most of the service applications will allow you to specify the database names in the UI unless you use the Wizard. If you want some wizard like experience and/or are setting up a lot of farms then you might want to take a look a [SPAutoInstaller](http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/)